# Hide/Show tablix row based on subreport results

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0, rdl

is it possible for me to hide/show a row in a tablix that contains a subreport based on the resultset count of the subreport?  basically, if there is no results in the subreport than don't display the row that it lives in.

Comment: I believe this may help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066644/sql-server-report-builder-hiding-tablix-rows-based-on-value-in-subreport

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the subReport if it doesn't return data.

Right click  in the SubReport ->Format Object ->Subreport -> Suppress Blank Subreport